# Editing TCP/IP Stack in Vmware ESXi 6

Tags: vmware

I've added another TCP/IP Stack to vmware 6 ESXi but I'm unable to edit it - or any other TCP/IP either, it's greyed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit it via CLI (esxcli).

First, list your netstack:

> esxcli network ip netstack list

I guess you've added new VMkernel interface as well, so in that example you want to set new network info for vmk adapter:

> esxcli network ip interface ipv4 set --interface-name=vmk1 --type=static --ipv4=192.1
>   68.100.222 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --gateway=192.168.100.1

Afterwards, VMK network looks like:

> esxcli network ip interface ipv4 get

```
Name  IPv4 Address     IPv4 Netmask     IPv4 Broadcast   Address Type  Gateway          DHCP DNS
----  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ------------  ---------------  --------
vmk0  99.211.211.116   255.255.255.240  99.211.211.127   STATIC        99.211.211.113      false
vmk1  192.168.100.222  255.255.255.0    192.168.100.255  STATIC        192.168.100.1     false
```